# Checksum verification for a file on two different hadoop file system

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, checksum

I am very new to Hadoop file system.
I have two different hadoop file systems(one is client and another is server),  both of them are in different domain and not having direct access to one another.

I want to copy files(in GB) from server to client.

Since I don't have direct access to server(from client), I followed below method to copy the files.

I wrote server java program which reads the file with server configuration and writing as bytes to stdout.

```
System.out.write(buf.array(), 0, length);
System.out.flush();
```

then, I wrote cgi script which call this server jar.

then, I wrote a client java program which calls above cgi script to read the data

```
FSDataOutputStream dataOut = fs.create(client_file, true, bufSize, replica, blockSize);
URL url = new URL("http://xxx.company.com/cgi/my_cgi_script?" + "file=" + server_file);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
byte[] byteChunk = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int n = 0;
while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
    dataOut.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    received += n;
}
dataOut.close();
```

now, copying file done without any issue and I see the same file size on server and client.

When I do FileChecksum for same file on client and server file systems, I am getting different values.

```
MD5-of-262144MD5-of-512CRC32C:86094f4043b9592a49ec7f6ef157e0fe
MD5-of-262144MD5-of-512CRC32C:a83a0b3f182db066da7520b36c79e696
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

**Note: I am using the same blockSize on client and server file systems**

Comment: **Additional info:** When I copy any file which is less than blockSize (with above method), then I am getting same FileChecksum on server and client file system.

Comment: any chance about different encoding conversion?